# How to determine if child was clicked in Jquery

Tags: jquery, onclick

Is there a ways in jQuery to tell which child was clicked if the onclick event was binded to the parent?

For instance:

```
  $('#daddy').click(function () {
    // if($("#son").isClicked()){return true;}
    //return false;
  });
```

and the markup looks like:

```
<div id="daddy">
  <span id="son"></span>
  <span id="daughter"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The event handler you pass to `click` will receive an `event` object as its first argument. The `target` of the event (i.e. the element that initiated the event) will be specified there.

Here's an example from the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
span, strong, p { 
  padding: 8px; display: block; border: 1px solid #999;  }
    </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="log"></div>
<div>
  <p>
    <strong><span>click</span></strong>
  </p>
</div>
<script>

$("body").click(function(event) {
  $("#log").html("clicked: " + event.target.nodeName);
});

</script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `event.target` will be either `<span id="son">` or `<span id="daughter">` if one of those two elements initiated the click event that bubbles up to the handler you have attached to `#daddy`. Use this property to determine which child was clicked. Voila!

Comment: I was using a jQuery .live listener and needed to stop propagation to the child using only a class name.  Using the above tip with one from another page I came up with: `if(!$(e.target).hasClass("customClass")) return false;` and it worked beautifully.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) to determine what was clicked:

```
  $('#daddy').click(function (e) {
      alert(e.target.id); // The id of the clicked element
  });
```

Here's a [simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/2MLDS/).

Answer (score 2):

This should be a different perspective at least:

```
$('#parent').on("click", function(evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
        if($.inArray(evt.currentTarget, $(this).children())){
            console.log(evt.currentTarget);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/frictionless/5qZ9u/) out

```
$(function() {
    $('#parent').delegate('a', 'click', function(evt) {
        debugger;
        evt.stopPropagation();
        alert($(evt.currentTarget).attr('id'));
    });
});​
```

Comment: Just a note from the jQuery docs: "As of jQuery 1.7, `.delegate()` has been superseded by the `.on()` method."

Answer (score 1):

use `event.target` to get the really clicked node:

```
$('#daddy span').on('click',function(event){
    if(event.target.nodeName=='BUTTON'){//Was clicked a button
        ....
    }
    if(event.target.id=='id'){//Was clicked #id
        ....
    }
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for an alternative

```
$('#daddy span').click(function () {
    var clicked = $(this).attr('id');
    if(clicked == "son"){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I know this is an option, but this isn't what I was looking for. I want to maintain the legacy code that it is.