# Javascript jQuery - find out if a child was clicked inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="videoWrapper" onclick="clickVideo(this);">
```

Javascript:

```
function clickVideo(so){
        var vid = $(so).find(".video");
```

I need to find out if the child `.volume` was clicked inside the element `so`

This: `log(so.target.class);` gives the error: `Cannot read property 'class' of undefined`

I know about this way: [How to determine if child was clicked in Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504997/how-to-determine-if-child-was-clicked-in-jquery) but is there a way to do it for my case?

Comment: What is `so` you passed to function? Is it the event?

Comment: @MMDM it's the clicked element, I need to find out if the child class ".volume" was clicked inside of it

Comment: I think `target` is the event property and can't access through another element. You can access it inside clicked element (in your case the parent element) and check if the `target` has same class as you want, then take action if it was.

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: Please edit your question to show enough of your "*[mcve]*" code that we can reproduce your problem. What's your HTML? Is there any other relevant JavaScript? CSS? What errors are you running into? What did you expect? What went wrong? It might be worth also refreshing your memory as to "*[ask]*" as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check snippet below:

Try click on first two colored elements and then other elements including parent and check the console.

```js
(function ($) {
  'use strict';
  
  $(function () {
    var parent = $('.parent'),
        child1 = parent.find('.child1'),
        child2 = parent.find('.child2');
        
    parent.on('click', function (e) {
      if ($(e.target).hasClass('child1')) {
        console.log('child1 has been clicked');
      } else if ($(e.target).hasClass('child2')) {
        console.log('child2 has been clicked');
      } else {
        console.log('other elements or parent has been clicked');
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.parent [class*='child'] {
  height: 30px;
}

.parent .child1 {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.parent .child2 {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.parent .child3 {
  background-color: #bbb;
}

.parent .child4 {
  background-color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
  <div class="child3"></div>
  <div class="child4"></div>
</div>
```

Say you have something like:

```js
anElement.on('click', function (e) {
  // here you call your function
  function clickVideo(this);

  // changed it to below
  function clickVideo(this, e);
});
```

or

```html
<!-- This is your element -->
<div class="videoWrapper" onclick="clickVideo(this);">
  ...
</div>

<!-- Changed to below -->
<div class="videoWrapper" onclick="clickVideo(this, event);">
  ...
</div>
```

Then you can work with event `e` as well:

```js
function clickVideo(so, e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement;

  var vid = $(so).find(".video");

  if ($(target).hasClass('child1')) {
    console.log('child1 has been clicked');
  } else if ($(e.target).hasClass('child2')) {
    console.log('child2 has been clicked');
  } else {
    console.log('other elements or parent has been clicked');
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are you using it? You should define events once, and not in some codes that call more than one time

Comment: But as the title says I need to check it inside the given function :/

Comment: You should call that function after knowing the clicked element is what you want, and that means you should call function **inside** the event handler.

Comment: I know I just said what happens when I set the listener inside the function where I want the check to be. On the first click nothing will happen except setting the listener first time. Please check the answer edit. What I basically want is to have everything inside the clickVideo function

Comment: OK, as you said the `so` is the clicked element. Where you define the click event? You should pass the `event` as well to this function that you can detect if it is the element you wanted and take action. I will edit answer...

Comment: This is how I call the function: <div class="videoWrapper" onclick="clickVideo(this);">

Comment: Yess the second solution is what I wanted :D Thanks!